# Are the CustomProperty objects in Excel VBA visible to the user anywhere in the user interface?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently began using the `CustomProperties` and `CustomProperty` objects in `Excel VBA`. I would like to know if these are visible or accessible to the user anywhere in the UI..?

I do understand the `CustomDocumentProperties` and `CustomDocumentProperty` objects ARE visible to the user through various UI controls, depending on the version of Excel.

I would like to use `CustomProperties` and `CustomProperty` for storing information I do not want the user to see, and so the user cannot change them.

I searched through Excel myself, but didn't find anything controls for them. I also searched on `StackOverflow` and `Google`, but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the answer to *if these are visible or accessible to the user anywhere in the UI..?* is No.  But it's hard to prove a negative, so I can't guarantee that.

That said, you seem to be wanting to store some sensitive data in an Excel workbook.  That is *never* going to be secure against a determined attacker.  At best you can discourage a responsible user from accessing it.

Comment: No, it's not sensitive data; it's just configuration settings for the macros. We have advanced Excel users and I don't want them to trip on any of the settings I build into the worksheets. I know nothing is secure. Just the fact that I can embed stuff in the worksheets in the first place means anyone else that knows VBA can get it out again.